# Is there an programmable audio mixer?

Tags: audio, audio-recording

I am looking for an audio mixer (preferably for Windows) that can mix and record channels based on a given criterion like:

Mute channel 2 when channel 1 is active. Put a gain gate on channel 1 (if the audio volume is low then mute it) etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can try one from this list (all of them useful and free):

- Cubase 10 Pro (https://www.steinberg.net/en/support/downloads/cubase_10.html)
- Tracktion (https://www.tracktion.com/products/waveform-free)
- Cakewalk (https://www.bandlab.com/products/cakewalk) I think this one is more useful for Windows
- Ardour (https://community.ardour.org/download)

Comment: Cubase is not free - these are trial version downloads. Steinberg used to distibute Cubasis with some keyboards that was limited/free but I don't believe they do anymore. Good call on windows cakewalk.

Answer (score 0):

[Ardour](https://ardour.org/) is probably the most full featured FOSS cross platform audio program available.